# Cropping Image to Center in Responsive Full Width Slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress, crop

I will prefix this by saying I am new to coding. I am modifying a child theme in wordpress.

I am attempting to center images within a responsive full width slider to crop from both the top and bottom evenly at it's widest width. I've tried a couple of different options with no success.

Here is a link to the website: http://50.87.248.76/~topheran/. It is for the initial slideshow at the top of the page.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT with HTML/CSS:
Thanks Jon for clarifying the etiquette for posting questions. Please let me know if I can add any further information.

Thanks again for any help.

HTML

`<div class="fullwidth_slider"><div class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
     <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators"><li class="active" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#fullwidth_slider"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#fullwidth_slider"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#fullwidth_slider"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="4" data-target="#fullwidth_slider"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="5" data-target="#fullwidth_slider"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-to="6" data-target="#fullwidth_slider"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"><img class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder image" src= "slide1.png" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h1></h1><p class="lead"><a class="btn btn  btn-lg" href="#section1"></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item "><img class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder image" src="slide2.png" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h1></h1><p class="lead"><a class="btn btn  btn-lg" href="#section2">k</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item "><img class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder image" src="slide3.png" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h1></h1><p class="lead"><a class="btn btn  btn-lg" href="#section3"></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item "><img class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder image" src="slide4.png" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h1></h1><a class="btn btn  btn-lg" href="#section4"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item "><img class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder image" src="slide5.png" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h1></h1><p class="lead"><a class="btn btn  btn-lg" href="section5"></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item "><img class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder image" src="slide6.png" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h1></h1><p class="lead"><a class="btn btn  btn-lg" href="#section6"></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item "><img class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder image"  src="slide7.png" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h1></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>`

CSS

```
`.fullwidth_slider {
   max-height: 975px;
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   z-index: 0;  
}
.fullwidth_slider .carousel-inner img{
   max-height: 100%;    
}
.slider_overlay {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.7);
   bottom: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 1;
}
.fullwidth_slider .carousel-inner img {
   border-radius: 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 1400px;
   z-index: 0;
   max-height: 100%;
}

.fullwidth_slider .carousel{
   display: block;
   max-height: 1050px;  
}
.fullwidth_slider .carousel-caption {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   border-radius: 0;
   float: none;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   top: 30%;
}
.fullwidth_slider .carousel-control{
   cursor:pointer;
   z-index: 999;    
}
.fullwidth_slider .carousel-indicators{
   bottom: 60px;    
}
.fullwidth_slider .carousel-caption h1 {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   display: block;
   margin-top: 0;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
.fullwidth_slider p.lead {
   color: #EBEDEF;
   font-size: 28px !important;
   line-height: 1.46429 !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 800px;
}
.fullwidth_slider .carousel-caption p {
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.72222;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 800px;
}
.fullwidth_slider .slider_overlay{
    z-index: 1;
}`
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please include any relevant code in the question itself. Links to external sites, particularly web sties that yo are working on are problematic. While you are working on the site you are not giving us a fixed point to work with. Once the site is fixed the question becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a WordPress tagged question, you can use the following code:

```
$image_width = 1280;
$image_height = 720;
add_image_size( 'Your_image_size_name', $image_width, $image_height, array( 'center', 'center' ) );
```

`$image_width` is currently set to 1280 and `$image_height` is set to 720. Both 1280 and 720 are number of pixels.

add_image_size() is the WordPress method for adding a new image size for each image you upload to your WordPress install. So each image you upload will have this size plus they will also be cropped from the center.

For more info about this go to

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

and to 
http://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/wordpress-thumbnail-crop

You can then use PHP's pathinfo() method like so and make your slideshow:

```
$IMG_parts = pathinfo( $img_url );
$html .= '<img src="'. $IMG_parts['dirname'] . '/' . $IMG_parts['filename'] . '-' . $your_image_width . 'x' . $your_image_height . $IMG_parts['extension'] . '"/>';
```

Of Course, this will have to be inside a unordered list and each image will be inside a list item tag. Also don't forget your alt text for your images.